# Options for accessing S3/DynamoDB with C/C++

Tags: c++, c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

I've been looking for a C/C++ interface to S3 and DynamoDB. I've found `libaws` on sourceforge that supports S3 but not dynamodb, but doesn't look like its maintained. Any pointers?

Comment: AWS maintains SDKs for certain languages, some third party ones exist in various forms for other languages. But in the end, they are just interface layers to a REST interface which you could access directly.

Comment: Amazon just released a C++ SDK. It is quite new and probably not realiable yet, but worth a check: https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/aws/introducing-the-aws-sdk-for-c/ & the Github: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-cpp

Answer (score 2):

I just came to the same crossroads myself. Unfortunately I couldn't find any reliable libraries so I'm writing it myself using POST as described:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/MakingHTTPRequests.html

I set up a persistent, non-blocking socket connection with AWS. I POST with send(...) and listen for responses on the AWS socket using libev, sending the client's socket to the callback so I can respond directly to users from the callback. This replicates the non-blocking calls that some of the official SDKs use, like the one for Node.js.

If you want more clarification, feel free to e-mail me: chris specificsymbol rockingdayo punctuation com

Answer (score 2):

For S3, there is [libaws](https://github.com/teltech/libaws).  You can also try and get the source code for [WebStor](http://www.meetup.com/Amazon-Web-Services-Official-Events/messages/boards/thread/22633112), (link in the blog post), but I haven't tried that one.

DynamoDB will be tougher, as it is a newer service.  Best bet is to follow Chris' suggestion and make the REST calls yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a recently released AWS DynamoDB library for C.  It is still under active development.  A previous (less feature-full) version of this has been used in a production environment for over a year.

https://github.com/devicescape/aws_dynamo